# How to hide break lines in textarea when pressing enter

Tags: php, javascript, html, textarea

I want to hide `<br />` in textarea when typing, but still want to save `<br />` when the enter is pressed for posting and then echoing it with broken lines, how can I do this?

Or is any other way to do this-> When user types text into textarea and presses enter, then goes to new line and when submitting I still can echo with broken lines. 
I'm detecting when the enter is pressed and putting `<br />` into with this code : 
`

```
<td><textarea id="opisId" onKeyPress="onTestChange()"; name="opis" cols="45" rows="15"></textarea></td><script>function onTestChange() {
var key = window.event.keyCode;

if (key == 13) {
    document.getElementById("opisId").value = document.getElementById("opisId").value + "<br />";
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

}         `

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the php function nl2br() or wrap  the input with `<pre></pre>`

Comment: O phuck, I did't know, that this (nl2br) is so easy... OMG :D I was inventing a warm water :S

Answer (score 0):

Why would you add `<br/>` upon user input? Just parse the textbox data on submission (or after getting the POST information if applicable) and change the *newline* characters accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` is not going to magically appear in an textarea unless you type it. `\n` < new lines can be replaced with the html `<br>` in php with the `nl2br()` function.

Comment: He actually stated (and posted code) on how he's parsing keycodes, detecting ENTER and adding `<br/>`.

Comment: oh, i did not scroll, what a bad idea in the first place.